# Customize the Local cost map

Tags: ros, rviz, turtlebot3, local-costmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,
Based on the ROS tutorial I added a simple layer to the global map as a plugin. the question is, How can I customize the local cost map as I want?
I attached a picture and I want to do the same. Based on the image, the shape of a dynamic obstacle is changing during navigation on the local cost map.
[Image link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wmZCJoxB8Qp27YgdfCSa5azFC60oPjU1/view?usp=sharing)
thank you for your support...

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/401321/customize-the-local-cost-map/) by [Morteza7](https://answers.ros.org/users/106029/morteza7/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2022-05-25

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joao.aguizo](https://answers.ros.org/users/61728/joao.aguizo/) on 2022-05-26**:
I could not quite grasp the image you provided, could you elaborate?

In any case, it is good to remember that, as the global, the local costmap is still, in fact, a *costmap*. That being said, the parameters are common to either one of them, making the way you configure them the factor that distinguishes one from the other. I would advice you to take a look into [these](http://wiki.ros.org/costmap_2d#costmap_2d.2Flayered.Parameters).

**Comment by [Morteza7](https://answers.ros.org/users/106029/morteza7/) on 2022-05-27**:
I added the image to the question. I want to do something like a picture...

**Comment by [joao.aguizo](https://answers.ros.org/users/61728/joao.aguizo/) on 2022-05-27**:
Still did not get it... You did not provide any additional information that might be useful. What is your end goal? Can you try explain what you are trying to achieve in that image that you provided?

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2022-05-27**:
Does the "customize the local cost map as I want" part mean something like a virtual obstacle that the robot sees as it moves? It would be something like in this set of packages for MiR: https://github.com/dfki-ric/mir_robot/tree/noetic - concretely:

```
# navigation:
roslaunch mir_navigation start_planner.launch \
    map_file:=$(rospack find mir_gazebo)/maps/maze.yaml \
    virtual_walls_map_file:=$(rospack find mir_gazebo)/maps/maze_virtual_walls.yaml
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solved it. I just used the simple layer tutorial and add my code to create the custom shape as a local cost map.
[simple layer tutorial](https://blog.birost.com/a?ID=00650-7a6275cc-1ffa-4492-a7a6-01a0de5a9c8e)

---

Originally posted by [Morteza7](https://answers.ros.org/users/106029/morteza7/) with karma: 31 on 2022-07-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1